# Creating ICICLE Chart using Highcharts Library

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization, icicle-diagram

I want to develop a ICICLE Chart as provided by d3 library using Highcharts Library. To the extent I googled, I couldn't find any samples of ICICLE Chart kind of Visualization Using Highcharts.

If this is really possible, please help me with how to create it.

Thanks.

Comment: Heat map seems like the easiest starting point. Remove the borders (or look to color them individually), and group parts of the rows together by color to form the bands...

Comment: Very basic proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/dannm3k6/

Comment: Thanks jlbriggs. Will have a first look on the fiddle. :)