# I need to develop icicle chart using HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, icicle-diagram

HI can I tweak tree map and do it ? 
I can pass all data hierarchy .
its already implemented in d3 .
Can i use/tweak Any properties of highcharts to render icicle ?

Comment: There is not a good way that I can see, but see my comment here for a rough proof of concept,using the heatmap type as a base:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358768/creating-icicle-chart-using-highcharts-library

Answer (score 0):

You could use `heatmap` - see this SO question: [Creating ICICLE Chart using Highcharts Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358768/creating-icicle-chart-using-highcharts-library)

Other way would be to use `treemap`. Unfortunately there is no default layout algorithm that would enable icicle chart, so it would have to be created.

How to create custom layout algorithm: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap

For icicle it will be better if children passed to layout algorithm will be unsorted. Feature can be changed by wrapping `setTreeValues` function.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c6bo2asn/

```
$(function () {
    //start wapper
    (function (H) {
        H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype, 'setTreeValues', function (proceed) {
            var tree = arguments[1];
            //setTreeValues: function (tree) {
            var series = this,
                childrenTotal = 0,
                sorted = [],
                val,
                point = series.points[tree.i];

            // First give the children some values
            H.each(tree.children, function (child) {
                child = series.setTreeValues(child);
                series.insertElementSorted(sorted, child, function (el, el2) {
                    return 0;//do not sort 
                });

                if (!child.ignore) {
                    childrenTotal += child.val;
                } else {
                    // @todo Add predicate to avoid looping already ignored children
                    series.eachChildren(child, function (node) {
                        H.extend(node, {
                            ignore: true,
                            isLeaf: false,
                            visible: false
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            // Set the values
            val = H.pick(point && point.value, childrenTotal);
            H.extend(tree, {
                children: sorted,
                childrenTotal: childrenTotal,
                // Ignore this node if point is not visible
                ignore: !(H.pick(point && point.visible, true) && (val > 0)),
                isLeaf: tree.visible && !childrenTotal,
                name: H.pick(point && point.name, ""),
                val: val
            });
            return tree;
        //},
        });
    }(Highcharts));    
    //end wapper
    //start layoutAlgorithm logic
    function myFunction(parent, children) {
        var childrenAreas = [],
            widthSoFar = 0,
            w;
        Highcharts.each(children, function (child,i) {
            if (child.level == 1) { //even lines
                childrenAreas.push({
                    x: parent.x,
                    y: parent.y + parent.height*(i/children.length),
                    width: parent.width,
                    height: parent.height/children.length
                });
            } else {
                w = parent.width * child.val/parent.val;
                childrenAreas.push({
                    x: parent.x + widthSoFar,
                    y: parent.y,
                    width: child.name === '_empty' ? 0 : w,
                    height: parent.height
                });
                widthSoFar += w;
            }
        });
        return childrenAreas;
    }
    //end layoutAlgorithm logic
    //assign new layoutAlgorithm logic
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.icicle = myFunction;
    //create chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'icicle',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function(){
                    //hide _empty
                    return this.key === '_empty' ? '' : this.key;
                },
                rotation: -90
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            levels: [{
                level: 2,
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            /*
            level 1 data points are lines
            */
            data: [{
                id: 'top',
                color: "#EC2500"
            }, {
                name: 'a Anne',
                parent: 'top',
                value: 50
            }, {
                name: 'a Rick',
                parent: 'top',
                value: 30
            }, {
                name: 'a Peter',
                parent: 'top',
                value: 20
            }, {
                id: 'second'
            }, {
                name: 'b Anne',
                parent: 'second',
                value: 30,
                color: "#ECE100"
            }, {
                name: '_empty',
                parent: 'second',
                value: 20
            }, {
                name: 'b Peter',
                parent: 'second',
                value: 30,
                color: "#EC9800"
            }, {
                name: '_empty',
                parent: 'second',
                value: 20
            }, {
                id: 'third',
                color: '#EC9800'
            }, {
                name: 'o Anne',
                parent: 'third',
                value: 20
            }, {
                name: 'o Rick',
                parent: 'third',
                value: 10
            }, {
                name: '_empty',
                parent: 'third',
                value: 70
            }, {
                id: 'last',
                color: '#669866'
            }, {
                name: '_empty',
                parent: 'last',
                value: 20
            }, {
                name: 'z Anne',
                parent: 'last',
                value: 10
            }, {
                name: '_empty',
                parent: 'last',
                value: 70
            }]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit consumption'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This helped me a lot ,